# Prove that equality holds in $\mathrm{Range \ }{ TS} \subseteq \mathrm{Range \ }{T}$ iff $\mathrm{Null \ }{T} + \mathrm{Range \ }{S} = V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $S: U \to V$ and $T: V \to W$ be linear maps between vector spaces. Suppose that $\mathrm{Range \ }{TS} \subseteq \mathrm{Range \ }{T}$.

$\longrightarrow$: Prove that if equality holds in $\mathrm{Range \ }{ TS} \subseteq \mathrm{Range \ }{T}$, then $\mathrm{Null \ }{T} + \mathrm{Range \ }{S} = V$.

$\longleftarrow$: Prove that if $\mathrm{Null \ }{T} + \mathrm{Range \ }{S} = V$, then equality holds in $\mathrm{Range \ }{ TS} \subseteq \mathrm{Range \ }{T}$.

I initially proved that $\mathrm{Range \ }{TS} \subseteq \mathrm{Range \ }{T}$, but I don't know how to move forward with the remaining "if and only if" portion of this proof. It somewhat makes sense intuitively when I look at $S$ and $T$ and their domain/codomain -- I just am stuck on how to show this rigorously.

EDIT: Formatting the question.

Comment: You are not supposed to prove that $\mathrm{Range \ }{TS} \subseteq \mathrm{Range \ }{T}$, this is part of the assumption. Since one inclusion is already given, you need to show that $\mathrm{Range \ }{TS} \supseteq \mathrm{Range \ }{T}$ if and only if $\mathrm{Null \ }T +\mathrm{Range \ }S=V$.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín There was a beginning portion of the proof that I left out, asking me to show that $Range{TS} \subseteq Range{T}$. I was just mentioning that to provide context.

Comment: $\operatorname{Range}(TS):=TS(U)\subset T(V)=\operatorname{Range}(T)$ no matter what.

Comment: I see, the way you worded your question assumed that as hypothesis, but as @OliverDiaz pointed out that's always true and it makes sense that you had to prove that first.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with  $ \text{Range}(T) = \text{Range}(TS)\implies \text{Null}(T) + \text{Range}(S)=V$.

Assume there exists $v \in V$ such that $v \notin \text{Null}(T) + \text{Range}(S)$. Since $Tv \in \text{Range}(TS)$ there exists $u \in U$ such that $TSu=Tv \implies 0=T(Su-v)$. can you see the contradiction?

For the other direction let's assume $\text{Null}(T)+\text{Range}(S)=V$ and let $x \in \text{Range}(T)$. Then there exists $v \in V$ such that $Tv=x$ and $v=v_0+v_S$ for some $v_0 \in \text{Null}(T)$ and $v_S \in \text{Range}(S)$. Then $x=Tv=Tv_S$. Now the proof is almost finished, can you figure out the rest?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the organization in your response. I am trying to show: (a) If equality holds in $Range{TS} \subseteq Range{T}$, then $Null{T} + Range{S} = V$, and the reverse implication for (b).

Comment: The equality holds when both sides are equal right? Equality for sets means that inclusions in both directions hold (everything that is in one of the sets is in the other and everything that is in the other is in the first one). Since you already know that $Range \ T \circ S \subset Range \ T$ equality of the sets is therefore equivalent to $Range  \ T \subset Range \ T \circ S$

Comment: I see what you're saying, thanks for the helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

Note, I will relabel $NullT$ with $kerT$ and $rangeT$ with $imT$ for any linear map $T$.

***Forward:***

Suppose $imT\circ S= imT$. We would like to show that $kerT+imS=V$. Trivially, $kerT+imS\subseteq V$. For the reverse inclusion, observe that if $v\in V$, then as $imT \subseteq imT\circ S$, there exists a $u\in U$, for which, $T(v-S(u))=\textbf{0}_W$. This implies that $v-S(u)\in KerT$. Hence,

$v=(v-S(u))+S(u) \in kerT+imS$.

***Backwards:***

Assume $kerT+imS=V$. We must verify that $imT\subseteq imT\circ S$. Let $T(v)\in imT$, where $v\in V$. By assumption, $v=v_1+S(u)$, where $v_1\in kerT$ and $u\in U$. By linearity of $T$, $T(v)=(T\circ S)(u)$. Therefore, $T(v)\in imT\circ S$.